# Comparing the results of four missing data imputation methods

Tags: missing-data, bias, mse, coverage-probability

Below are the Bias, MSE and Coverage of four missing data imputation methods at different percentages of missing values. From these we can see that, `m4` method gives less bias in all the cases but it gives larger MSE and smaller Coverage than other methods as the percentage of missing values increases.

```
#for 10% missing values     
                 m1         m2         m3         m4         
Bias           -0.040     -0.031     -0.034      0.006    
MSE             0.028      0.030      0.029      0.035    
Coverage        97.000     96.700     96.500     94.400


#for 30% missing values
                 m1         m2        m3           m4 
Bias           -0.100    -0.080     -0.085       -0.056
MSE             0.043     0.044      0.043        0.051
Coverage        95.100    95.300     95.000       92.500

#for 50% missing values
                  m1        m2         m3        m4
Bias            -0.18     -0.155     -0.160    -0.144
MSE              0.07      0.070      0.068     0.075
Coverage         92.30     92.500     92.500    85.500
```

Now i have two questions regarding this

1. What can we say about the `m4` method compared to other methods?
2. What inference can we draw from this?(which one is performing better and why?)

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Good question, but I am missing some information: am I seeing the average of multiple single imputations, the result of a pooled multiple imputation, or the average of multiple pooled multiple imputations? Further, what is the difference between the models? Type, included predictors, etc. And, is the missing mechanism known? All these could influence the interpretation. Could you elaborate on them?